# Get style in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to resize a `div` when the size of the div is 50% to 100%. But when I try to `console.log` the current size of the `div` it just logs whitespace... Whats wrong?

```
window.onload = function() {
    //declare vars
    var fullbox = document.getElementById('box'),
        minBut = document.getElementById('down');

    minBut.onclick = function() {
        if(fullbox.style.width == "50%") {
            fullbox.style.width = "100%";
        } else {
            fullbox.style.width = "50%";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add on click event in that div element not in the function.

Comment: can you setup a JSFiddle with your example

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5qnNa/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that could be the case when the width has not been initialized for that element before.
The second time it should be 50%.

tested with adding `alert(fullbox.style.width);`

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2BbqT/)

Comment: Indeed, when i click twice now it works, but should i use px instead of % ? i did gave the ID styles in CSS.

Comment: .style.width will always return a pixel value no matter if you set a percentage or not

Comment: So i should go on with pixels in this case.. Thanks !